# TeamCity and ProGet

Tags: teamcity, proget

After changing TeamCity to use the ProGet packaging service instead of the built in service, I keep getting an error that an API key is required. How would I be able to pass the ApiKey that I set up for the service in the url that I am using to access the service in TeamCity RgPublish command line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe TeamCity requires that the APIkey is passed in, regardless of if the feed requires it or not. You can just use name:pass as the api key in this case.